# 'ModuleNotFoundError' Jupyter Notebook even though module was installed with pip

Tags: pip, conda, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run some code in jupyter notebook which needs the module 'CTRNN' installed. I can not install with conda, so I installed with pip (which are the instructions on the pypi page for ctrnn module anyway). However, even though I can see the ctrnn module is installed within the env I am using, I still get this error message.

The environments also match up with where ctrnn was installed
Jupyter notebook:

active environment : tf

active env location : /Users/logan/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf

Path of ctrnn install:/Users/logan/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages

What is going on here? I have no idea how to fix this. Any help greatly appreciated!